# Mathematica 12.3.1 Apple M1

Tags: mac-os-x, compatibility, apple-silicon

Mathematica version 12.3.1 just recently came out, and one of the biggest things is the support for apple silicon, the M1...I completely uninstalled version 12.3 and just reinstalled 12.3.1 to do some testing...after benchmarking and not getting a better result than on rosetta 2, I checked in in activity monitor if it's reporting running on the new Apple silicon, to find  the new version is *not* running natively on the M1 chip.

[image]

Is this the case for every/any one else? Is there something specific that needs to be done?

Comment: Make sure you download the correct Mac version from the portal. You should see two; you want 'Mathematica_12.3.1_MACARM_DLM.dmg'.

Comment: Whoooops....didn't see that one! :D

Comment: @kirkus Make that an answer please. This will be a recurring question.

Comment: @kirkus yes make that an answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: Also, setting `SetSystemOptions["ParallelOptions" -> "ParallelThreadNumber" -> 4];` can help some of the linear algebra routines. Try changing the number and varying the number to see if things improve.

Comment: @CraigCarter did you mean to post that comment on my benchmarking thread?

Comment: No, that was something that improved my performance with the M! Chip for the MACARM release specifically.

Comment: @CraigCarter oh interesting..maybe make an example in my benchmarking thread ?  or make a question and answer it yourself? I‘d actually be curious to see the differences in a working example.

Comment: @morbo good idea. I will.  However, that was a “pre-release” of the ARM distribution. I’ll check and see if that still applies in the latest release.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you download the correct Mac version from the portal. I see two in my portal; you want **Mathematica_12.3.1_MAC-ARM_DLM.dmg** (download manager) or **Mathematica_12.3.1_MAC-ARM.dmg** (full installer). The Download File Information dialog will indicate **Platform: macOS for Apple Silicon**.