# M1Pro benchmarks off?

Tags: benchmarking, apple-silicon

My MacbookAir M1 provided inspiring results for `BenchmarkReport[]` ... a score of 3.18. I was excited to run this on my new MBPro with M1Max... and got a very low score, 0.21

```
{"MachineName" -> "office-mbp", "System" -> "Mac OS X ARM (64-bit)",
 "BenchmarkName" -> "WolframMark", "FullVersionNumber" -> "12.3.1",
 "Date" -> "December 16, 2021", "BenchmarkResult" -> 1.352, "TotalTime" -> 10.235,
 "Results" -> {{"Data Fitting", 0.371}, {"Digits of Pi", 0.166},
               {"Discrete Fourier Transform", 0.315}, {"Eigenvalues of a Matrix", 2.085},
               {"Elementary Functions", 0.498}, {"Gamma Function", 0.213},
               {"Large Integer Multiplication", 0.181}, {"Matrix Arithmetic", 0.257},
               {"Matrix Multiplication", 0.264}, {"Matrix Transpose", 0.196},
               {"Numerical Integration", 0.873}, {"Polynomial Expansion", 0.052},
               {"Random Number Sort", 0.396}, {"Singular Value Decomposition", 3.359},
               {"Solving a Linear System", 1.009}}}
```

A puzzle to me. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try the full benchmark report and see if one operation in particular is holding everything back (maybe driver or library issue), or if all steps are slow.

Comment: Perhaps you can post the full results of `Benchmark[]` as well.

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you running?  Do you have any processes running under Rosetta (`Kind` is `Intel` in Activity Monitor)?

Comment: Related [thread](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2118125) on the Wolfram Community site.

Comment: Are you running the correct version of Mathematica that runs natively on the M1 chip? According to this post (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250776/mathematica-12-3-1-apple-m1) there are two different versions. One for M1 macs and 1 for Intel Macs.

Comment: To be clear, the link from @Nate applies to V12.3.  V13 is universal, so there is a single download that contains both Intel and Apple Silicon versions and automatically runs the correct one.

Comment: For 12.3, this has been improved with a paclet update (it may however take a couple of days to be delivered depending on when the last check for updates was). The expected  score (assuming the machine is otherwise idle) should be around 3.4 and similar to the V13 result.

Comment: Just uploaded Mathematica 13 and ran that one...score is 3.12, only marginally better than the MBAir with M1. That surprises me.

Comment: If you run LaunchKernels[] before running the Benchmark test, you should see improvement. It seems that without launching the kernels, it restricts the benchmark tests to only being able to access one core.

Comment: I am having also some unexpected results. With my old 2018 i5-8259U 16GB RAM macbook I get 3.14 and 6.16 after LauchKernels[] (4 KernelObjects created). With my new 2021 M1 Pro 10c 16GB RAM MacBook I get only 2.55 and 7.73 after LauchKernels[] (4 kernels). I see the OP reports very slow results for test "Singular Value Decomposition". I also see very slow results for that test in particular (6x time compared to the intel machine). Maybe that helps someone who nows better than me :)

Answer (score 2):

Site questions in principle should be answerable, even if practically that's not always possible. "Any thoughts?" is pretty broad, but since this question has not been closed, here is what seems the most authoritative response from the comments:

> For 12.3, this has been improved with a paclet update (it may however take a couple of days to be delivered depending on when the last check for updates was). The expected score (assuming the machine is otherwise idle) should be around 3.4 and similar to the V13 result. – ilian Dec 17, 2021 at 1:17